# Angular5 Openlayers4

Tags: angular, openlayers, visibility, layer

I am trying to create a map with multiple layers which I can setvisible false or true. This is my code to set up the map:

```
  this.map = new OlMap({
              target: 'map',
              layers: [
                new OlTileLayer({
                  source: new OSM()
                }), new Group({
                  layers: [
                    new OlTileLayer({
                      source: new TileJSON({
                        url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.20110804-hoa-foodinsecurity-3month.json?secure',
                        crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
                      })
                    }),
                    new OlTileLayer({
                      source: new TileJSON({
                        url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.world-borders-light.json?secure',
                        crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
                      })
                    })
                  ]
                })
              ],
              view: this.view
            });
```

It works fine I can see the map and all the Layers. With a checkbox I want to set a certain layer to false or true.

How can i get the id of every layer that I have added and how can I set the visibility to false. I am using openlayers4 with Angular5

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First I would define my layers out of the map controls as a variable because then they can be turned and off with an event listener on your check box easily. The syntax here is going to be a little different because I'm not using Angular but the functionality is the same.

```
var floodZones=new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
  extent: [-8459941, 4191197.5, -8400060, 4333020.5],
  url:'/geoserver/Property_Map/wms',
  params: {'Layers':'Property_Map:flood_3857', 'TILED':true},
  transition:0,
  serverType:'geoserver',
  version: '1.1.0'
 })
});



document.getElementById("flood").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(!toggleFlood){
     map.removeLayer(floodZones)
  } else {
  map.addLayer(floodZones)
  }
  toggleFlood=!toggleFlood
  });
window.toggleFlood=true;
```

Comment: the problem with this is when I have 10 layers i will need to define 10 variables

Comment: Yep, I have 12, copy and paste and then changing the names and parameters if your friend. If they aren't named then how will your check-box know which one to turn on/off??

Comment: while they have a fixed number its fine to create that number of variables, if you prefer you can add them to an array

Answer (score 0):

If you have id or any other property defined to your layers you can get them using `map.getLayers()` and use `foreach` to find the layer with that property using `layer.get()`

Example:

```
new OlTileLayer({
    id: 'osm',
    source: new OSM()
})
```

You can get this layer and set visible using this

```
map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer) {
    if(layer.get('id') == 'osm') {
        layer.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

To implement this with a checkbox you will probably have to assign that layer property as checkbox value and compare with `layer.get('id')`

Note that it doesn't have to be `id` you can use any name you like. And seems like you are using layer groups and if you want to get the layer of a group you need to get layers from the group instead of map like `layergroup.getLayers()`